# Python fetch MySQLdb results in chunks with generator - error

Tags: python, generator, mysql-python

I have the following code:

```
def executeQuery(conn, query):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    return cur

def trackTagsGenerator(chunkSize, baseCondition):
    """ Returns a dict of trackId:tag limited to chunkSize. """

    sql = """
        SELECT track_id, tag
        FROM tags 
        WHERE {baseCondition}
    """.format(baseCondition=baseCondition)

    limit = chunkSize
    offset = 0
    while True:
        trackTags = {}

        # fetch the track ids with the coresponding tag
        limitPhrase = " LIMIT %d OFFSET %d" % (limit, offset)
        query = sql + limitPhrase
        offset += limit
        cur = executeQuery(smacConn, query)
        rows = cur.fetchall()

        if not rows:
            break

        for row in rows:
            trackTags[row['track_id']] = row['tag']

        yield trackTags
```

I want to use it like this:

```
for trackTags in list(trackTagsGenerator(DATA_CHUNK_SIZE, baseCondition)):        
    print trackTags
    break
```

This code produces the following error without even fetching one chunk of track tags:

```
Exception _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now") in <bound method SSDictCursor.__del__ of <MySQLdb.cursors.SSDictCursor object at 0x10b067b90>> ignored
```

I suspect it's because I have the query execute logic in the body of loop in the generator function.

Is someone able to tell me how to fetch chunks of data using mysqldb in such way?

Comment: I would refrain from using `fetchall()` after all. Instead, iterate over the complete result and yield things (pairs?) as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is because it can run into situations where you've got two queries
running simultaniously because of the *yield*. Depending on how you call the function (threads, async, etc..) I'm pretty sure your cursor might get clobbered too?

As well, you're opening yourself up to (sorry, but I can't sugar coat this part) horrific SQL injection holes by inserting baseConditional using essentially a printf. Take a look at the  DB-API’s parameter substitution docs for help.

Yield isn't going to save you time or energy here at all, the full sql command will always need to run before you'll get a single result. (Hence you're using LIMIT and OFFSET to make it more friendly, kudos)

i.e. someone updates the table while you're yielding out some data, in this particular case - not the end of the world. In many others, it gets ugly.

If you're just goofing around and you want this to work 'right-now-dammit', it'd probably work to modify executeQuery as such:

```
 def executeQuery(conn, query):
     cur = conn.cursor()
     cur.execute(query)
     cur = executeQuery(smacConn, query)
     rows = cur.fetchall()
     cur.close()
     return rows
```

One thing that also kinda jumps out at me - you define trackTags = {}, but then you update tagTrackIds, and yield trackTags.. Which will always be empty dict.

My suggestion would be to not bother yourself with the headache of hand writing SQL if you're just trying to get a hobby project working. Take a look at [Elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki) which is built on top of [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

Using an ORM (object-relational-mapper) can be a much more friendly introduction to databases. Defining what your objects look like in Python, and having it automatically generate your schema for you - and being able to add/modify/delete things in a Pythonic manner is really nifty.

If you really need to be async, check out [ultramysql](https://github.com/esnme/ultramysql) python module.

Comment: 1) The code does not rely on threads.
2) The {baseCondition} is not user-input. It's a cron data processor, the {baseCondition} is still ugly, but created in very safe manner, also the user that fetches the data is read-only mysql user. What I try to say is, I know how to take care of injections.
3) The data amounts are huge. Lets say this table is few gigabytes, without the indexes. So I can not do simply "fetchall", thus the chunks generator. 4) I edited the code, I changed some var names from the original code when pasting it here.

Comment: If you're using LIMIT and OFFSET in your query and you can't run fetchall then your LIMIT is too big. Whats the point of using LIMIT if you can't fetchall the results?

Comment: Hm, I do fetchall inside the loop, is that what you say is best to avoid?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's leaving the cursor open thats the problem. Close the cursor, return the rows from your execQuery function and you should be fine.

Comment: BTW: MySQL supports a file way to get a cursor: `with conn as cursor: ...`. This handles transactions neatly as well as closes the cursor if needed. (Although I don't think that the not closed cursor is the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

You use a `SSDictCursor`, something that maps to `mysql_use_result()` on MySQL-API-side. This requires that you read out the complete result before you can issue a new command.

As this happens before you receive the first chunk of data after all: are yu sure that this doesn't happen in the context of the query *before* this part of code is executed? The results of that last query might be still in the line, and executing the next one (i. e., the fist one in *this* context) might break things...